# Echo after ms sql fetch array does not run

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SMQL select query which retrieves data from MS Sql server but after the `mssql_query`, I tried fetching it thru a loop which uses `mssql_fetch` array but it seems it is skipping the fetch part. Here's my code.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $account = $_REQUEST['name'];
 ?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
         <?php
             echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'  width='100%''>";
            echo "<tr><th>No.</th><th>Location</th><th>Engine</th>   <th>Time</th></tr>";

        // Loop through database

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM locations where name = '$account' order by time desc";
        //die($sql);
        $result = mssql_query($sql);

          while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $location = $row['address'];
            $engine = $row['description'];
            $time = $row['time'];



            // Show entries
                echo    "<tr>
                         <td>".$id."</td>
                         <td>".$location."</td>
                         <td>".$engine."</td>
                         <td>".$time."</td>
                         </tr>";

        }

        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this seems like an obvious question, but is your query returning any data?

Comment: it does. It does return values.

Comment: figured it out. I had the require database connection. Sorry